# How can I lock the repo so that I'm next in line to merge?

Tags: gitlab

We have a large team of > 50 developers at work. Code is merged to master via Merge Requests (MR), and each merge request must be reviewed and approved by any other teammate. The problem is that I am sometimes stuck in a MR/rebase race. I try to merge, fail, someone else snuck in an MR before me. So I rebase. Try to merge, fail, someone else snuck in before me. So I rebase. Sometimes it takes 2-3 rebases before I win the race.

Is there a way in GitLab to "reserve" the right to merge so that you are guaranteed next in line? Or at least say: "You can't merge because another user has reserved a file you are trying to modify". It seems silly that I have to keep wasting time rolling the dice to see if my code merges.

The VCS we used before (ClearCase) had this exact mechanism. You could "reserve" files such that only you were allowed to check them in. Anyone else would be rejected (besides admins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab EE allows [file locking](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html) and informs during the Merge Request that the file is locked:

> When a user that is not the author of the locked state of a file
>   accepts a merge request, an error message will appear stating that the
>   file is locked.

Merge requests can also be [prioritized using labels or issue deadlines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html#filtering-issues-merge-requests-and-epics-by-label). You can check [this question about merge request priority](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/merge-request-priority/20299) and [how GitLab community are organizing them](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/labels.html?utf8=%E2%9C%93&subscribed=&search=priority)

Comment: Ah, I saw file locking, but it seemed like it was only a pre-receive hook that rejected pushes. Good to know it can be used to ensure someone doesn't sneak in an MR on a file I've modified.